# Regression with additional term

Tags: regression, probability

This may be a rather silly question, but I was wondering if there was a name/specific techniques for the following problem. I have some dataset with X,Y values. I know that $y_i=f(x_i)+h_i+e_i $for some function $f(\cdot)$, some arbitrary value h_i (which are distributed around 0 and assumed to be independent from $x_i$, but may correlate with $y_i$) and some small error $e_i$. Presumably than I should be able to determine $f(x_i)$ with some regression technique and then should be able to determine estimated values for h_i.

Comment: You included the [tag:Bayesian] tag. What do you want to do that is Bayesian?

Comment: Fair point. I was sort of messing with my question and didn't really know how to ask it or what tags to put and bayesian tag definitely doesn't fit the question I wrote. Sorry about that. Removed the inaccurate tag.

Comment: If we write $\epsilon_i = h_i + e_i$ then $y_i=f(x_i) + \epsilon_i$ so I can't see how you can do what you want. The model would be unidentified.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a name for this. This isn't a request for something complex. Its just a badly worded question asking if an obvious thing has a name. The only thing that I was wondering about is when a regression technique introduces additional errors, and whether there were any methods to prevent this.

Comment: @SamH you can have models with additional errors, e.g. [random-effects models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_effects_model), but the errors are modeled using some kind of additional information.

Comment: That seems somewhat like the term I wanted.  I think I was pretty unclear with the question but what I was looking for was whether or not there was a term for specifically trying to determine $h_i$. That is to say, the end goal isn't to predict $y_i$ as well as possible, but rather to predict $y_i$ so that I can use $y_i-p_i$ as an estimation for $h_i$.

Comment: @SamH so you have in mind some kind of latent variable model. The problem is, as stated in my answer, that you don't have relevant data to distinguish the latent variable from the noise. You would need some additional information that can be used to differentiate them. Otherwise, its unidentifiable.

Answer (score 3):

How would you distinguish $h_i$ from $e_i$? Without additional information you can’t. $y_i - f(x_i) =h_i + e_i$, how would you know how much of the residual from the difference comes from $h_i$ vs $e_i$? This is an equation with two unknowns, with unlimited number of equivalent solutions.

Comment: Obviously you can't. But I don't know that you need to differentiate between h and e. Say you have some third set of numbers S that you expect to correlate with $h_i$.  Then this would give you method to obtain the relationship between S and H (with obviously, larger errors in the second part).

Comment: @SamH that's why I said, "without additional information". If you have additional information, then the model would depend on what exactly the information is. The simplest case would be something like $y_i = f(x_i) + g(s_i) + e_i$.